# Display Same Row Number In Two Seperate Columns In Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv that I'm working with right now that fundamentally looks something like this (see picture).

Sample CSV[image: Sample CSV]

What I'd like to be able to output is the corresponding row in the UTC Time column for the Value 1, 2, or 3 column when it exceeds a threshold e.g. print all rows in UTC Time and the values of Value 2 when it exceeds 2. In this case, it would print:

1/1/2018 13:40 3
1/1/2018 13:41 4
...

Right now it's just print T/F when I do something like this:

df['UTC Time'].where(Value 2 > 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try :

```
 df[['UTC Time','Value 2']][df['Value 2']>2]
```

Comment: That gives me the UTC Time so that partially works! How do I get it to print the value for Value 2 as well?

Comment: df[['UTC Time','Value 2']][df['Value 2']>2]